# JavaScript split and join

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, `15.Prototypal-Inheritance-and-Refactoring-the-Slider.txt`, I'd like to make it looks like `15.Prototypal...-Slider.txt`

The `length` of the text is `56`, how can I keep the first 12 letters and 10 last letters (incuding punctuation marks) and replace the others to `...`

I don't really know how to commence the code, I made something like

```
var str="15.Prototypal-Inheritance-and-Refactoring-the-Slider.txt";
str.split("// ",1);
```

although this gives me what I need, how do I have the results base on letters not words.

Comment: No it doesn't return what you think. It returns the entire string, but in case you're using Firebug, the string representation inside an array is abbreviated like that. Do `str.split("// ",1)[0];` to see the real returned string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [str.slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp).

```js
function middleEllipsis(str, a, b) {
  if (str.length > a + b)
    return str.slice(0, a) + '...' + str.slice(-b);
  else
    return str;
}

middleEllipsis("15.Prototypal-Inheritance-and-Refactoring-the-Slider.txt", 12, 10);
// "15.Prototypa...Slider.txt"

middleEllipsis("mpchc64.mov", 12, 10);
// "mpchc64.mov"
```

Comment: Not a fan of the name but it's as good as it gets. Wonder what a good name for this would be?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if the length is small, like this name`mpchc64.mov`, the result looks incorrect

Answer (score 2):

This function will do what you ask for:

```
function fixString(str) {
  var LEN_PREFIX = 12;
  var LEN_SUFFIX = 10;
  if (str.length < LEN_PREFIX + LEN_SUFFIX) { return str; }
  return str.substr(0, LEN_PREFIX) + '...' + str.substr(str.length - LEN_SUFFIX - 1);
}
```

You can adjust the LEN_PREFIX and LEN_SUFFIX as needed, but I've the values you specified in your post. You could also make the function more generic by making the prefix and suffix length input arguments to your function:

```
function fixString(str, prefixLength, suffixLength) {
  if (str.length < prefixLength + suffixLength) { return str; }
  return str.substr(0, prefixLength) + '...' + str.substr(str.length - suffixLength - 1);
}
```

Comment: You can just do `str.substr(-LEN_SUFFIX)` I believe.

Comment: Hi @BillCriswell. I haven't seen that kind of notation before. Could you give the complete line so I can try it out?

Comment: `'bill'.substr(-2)` would return `'ll'`.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'd like to make it looks like **15.Prototypal...-Slider.txt***
>   <kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ubuleq/6/edit)**</kbd>

**No matter how long are the suffixed and prefixed texts**, this will get the desired:

```
var str = "15.Prototypal-Inheritance-and-Refactoring-the-Slider.txt",
    sp = str.split('-'),
    newStr = str;
if(sp.length>1) newStr =  sp[0]+'...-'+ sp.pop() ;

alert( newStr ); //15.Prototypal...-Slider.txt
```

Splitting the string at `-` and using `.pop()` method to retrieve the last Array value from the splitted String.
**Instead of splitting the string at some defined positions** it'll also handle strings like:

**11.jQuery-infinite-loop-a-Gallery.txt**
 returning:
  **11.jQuery...-Gallery.txt**

Comment: I don't think that's what the questions's asking.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand sure, it's even better

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.  Note that this keeps the first 13 characters and last 11 because that's what you gave in your example.:

```
var shortenedStr = str.substr(0, 13) + '...' + str.substring(str.length - 11);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the javascript substring command to find out what you want.

If you string is always 56 characters you could do something like this:

```
var str="15.Prototypal-Inheritance-and-Refactoring-the-Slider.txt";


var newstr = str.substring(0,11) + "..." + str.substring(45,55)
```

if your string varies in length I would highly recommend finding the length of the string first, and then doing the substring.

have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp